# Can you call different constructors based on different template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Is there an way to call different constructors of same class based on different template parameter.

```
template<class T>
class X {
  public:
    T a;
    X<char>() {
      std::cout << "char ctor called" << std::endl;
    }
    X<int>() {
      std::cout << "int ctor called" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  X<char> x;
  X<int> y;
}
```

I think constructors in the class are not valid, but is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways:

- (full) specialization of the member:

  ```
  template<class T>
  class X {
    public:
      T a;
      X();
  };

  template <>
  X<char>::X() : a('\0') { std::cout << "char ctor called" << std::endl; }

  template <>
  X<int>::X() : a(0) { std::cout << "int ctor called" << std::endl; }
  ```
- Specialize the whole class (so requires to duplicate some code though)

  ```
  template<class T>
  class X;

  template <>
  class X<char> {
    public:
      char a;
      X() : a('\0') { std::cout << "char ctor called" << std::endl; }
  };
  template <>
  class X<int> {
    public:
      int a;
      X() : a(0) { std::cout << "int ctor called" << std::endl; }
  };
  ```
- `if constexpr` of C++17 (but doesn't handle initializer list):

  ```
  template<class T>
  class X {
    public:
      T a;
      X() : a(0) {
          if constexpr (std::is_same_v<char, T>) {
              std::cout << "char ctor called" << std::endl;
          } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>) {
              std::cout << "int ctor called" << std::endl;
          }
      }
  };
  ```
- `requires` for C++20:

  ```
  template<class T>
  class X {
    public:
      T a;
      X() requires(std::is_same_v<char, T>) : a('\0') {
              std::cout << "char ctor called" << std::endl;
      }
      X() requires(std::is_same_v<int, T>) : a(0) {
          std::cout << "int ctor called" << std::endl;
      }
  };
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if constexpr`:

```
template <class T>
class X {
public:
    // ...
    X()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
            // ...
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, char>) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another alternative - tag dispatch:

```
template<class T>
class X {
public:
    // ...

    X() : X(Tag<T>{}) {}

private:
    template<class> struct Tag {};

    X(Tag<char>) {
        // ...
    }

    X(Tag<int>) {
        // ...
    }

    template<class U> X(Tag<U>) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

You can do this:

```
 template<class T>
class X {
public:
    T a;
    X() {
        std::cout << "basic template\n" ;
    }

};
template<>
class X<char>  {
public:
    char a;
    X() {
        std::cout << "char ctor called\n" ;
    }
};
template<>
class X<int> {
public:
    int a;
    X() {
        std::cout << "int ctor called\n";
    }
};

int main(){
X<int> xint;
     X<char> xchar;
     X<string> xstring;
return 0;
}
```

You will see in the output window:

```
int ctor called
char ctor called
basic template
```

Comment: this is not wrong, but specializing the whole class will require to repeat all methods not only the constructor